# "Misplaced \noalign" error with datatool

Tags: debugging, datatool

Attempting to compile the following file gives the following error:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\pagebreak ->\noalign 
                      {\ifnum `}=0\fi \@testopt {\LT@no@pgbk -}4
l.47 \end{letter}
```

I don't understand why. Making minor changes to the csv file `xx.csv` makes this error go away. For example, change `mm` to `m`. Alternatively, change `mm` to `11`.

Alternatively, adding a comma to the end of the string `2014.02.26,26,2014.11.12.tm` in

```
\PrintDocTableParekh[2014.02.26,26,2014.11.12.tm]{newbDB}{Documents}
```

thus changing it to `2014.02.26,26,2014.11.12.tm,` also makes the error go away.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[verbose]{datatool}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}

\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l}{#1}}
\newcommand{\nextnuml}[1]{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum.\label{#1}}
\newcommand*{\checkmissing}[1]{\DTLifnull{#1}{}{#1}}
\signature{Someone}
\newcommand{\PrintDocTableParekh}[3][]{%
 % #1 = list of rowIDs
 % #2 = database to search
 % #3 =caption
  \begin{longtable}{r l p{1.5in} c c p{2.5in}}
    \caption{#3}\\
   & \colhead{Date} & \colhead{Filename} & \colhead{From} & \colhead{To} & \colhead{Subject}\\\hline\endhead
    \DTLforeach
    [\ifblank{#1}{\boolean{true}}{\DTLisSubString{#1}{\RowID}}]
    {#2}{%
      \RowID=RowID,%
      \Date=Date,%
      \Filename=Filename,%
      \From=From,%
      \To=To,%
      \Subject=Subject%
    }{%
      \nextnuml{\RowID} & \Date & {\bfseries\expandafter\url\expandafter{\Filename} } & \checkmissing{\From} & \checkmissing{\To} & \Subject \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%

\begin{filecontents*}{xx.csv}
2014.02.26,       26 Feb 2014      , something.txt     ,      ,    ,    ,subject
2014.11.12.tm,    12 Nov 2014      , something.txt     , XXX  , YY ,    , subject
mm, date, ,,,, subject
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
  \opening{xx,}
  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}
  \DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Date,Filename,From,To,Email,Subject}]{newbDB}{xx.csv}
  \PrintDocTableParekh[2014.02.26,26,2014.11.12.tm]{newbDB}{Documents}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: no time to look now but you never finish the longtable

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure what you mean. Is there something wrong with the syntax I am using?

Comment: I was out all day, may look later but the reason you get that error is that after the command you are still inside the longtable, so it's as if you had `\end{letter}` inside the table.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, you should know, certainly. But I have `\end{longtable}` right there. What more could I do to end it?

Comment: putting `\endgroup\end{longtable}` before `\end{letter}` makes the document complete (with some warnings) showing that in this document the `\end{longtable}` in your macro was never executed and you have to close the table by hand. I'm not sure I know datatool well enough to trace this just now, may look another day.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Huh, that's weird. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with `\DTLifSubString` when used within `\DTLforeach`. (This includes using `\DTLisSubString` in the conditional argument.) The use of `letter` and `longtable` are obfuscating matters, so here's a trimmed down version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{xx.csv}
2014.02.26
2014.11.12.tm
mm
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand*{\ifcontainsrowid}[2]{%
 \ifblank{#1}{#2}%
 {%
   \DTLifSubString{#1}{\RowID}{#2}{}%
 }%
}    

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID}]{newbDB}{xx.csv}

\DTLforeach*{newbDB}{\RowID=RowID}%
{%
   \ifcontainsrowid{2014.02.26,26,2014.11.12.tm}%
   {%
      \RowID
   }
}%

\end{document}
```

This causes a different error message:

```
Runaway argument?
\expandafter \dtl@ifsingle \expandafter {\dtl@first }{\expandafter \@dtl@testif
substring \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \dtl@getfirst was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

But it stems from the same problem. I haven't worked out what's causing it yet, but I've been away for a week and need to catch up on things so I haven't had much of a chance to investigate yet. You can get around it by using a different command, for example `\IfSubStr` from the `xstring`  package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{filecontents*}{xx.csv}
2014.02.26
2014.11.12.tm
mm
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand*{\ifcontainsrowid}[2]{%
 \ifblank{#1}{#2}%
 {%
   %\DTLifSubString{#1}{\RowID}{#2}{}%
   \IfSubStr{#1}{\RowID}{#2}{}%
 }%
}


\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID}]{newbDB}{xx.csv}

\DTLforeach*{newbDB}{\RowID=RowID}%
{%
   \ifcontainsrowid{2014.02.26,26,2014.11.12.tm}%
   {%
      \RowID
   }
}%

\end{document}
```

Update: This bug has been fixed in v2.23.